# How to handle with 2 pan gestures that affect over one view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I have 2 pan gestures in the screen and i want in only one case when i swipe left only one of the gestures to be called. I tryed `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` to enable both gestures.
Thanks

Comment: Will you please describe the scenario in more detail.

Comment: It sounds like you want Swipe Gesture Recognizers not Pan Gesture Recognizers.

Comment: Not exactly, I have one view that has pan but over this view affects pan gesture from main menu also. The reason is that i want only when i swipe left, only gesture from view to be called in all other cases i want both to be called

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is just get the translation point from the method,

```
- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view
```

and compute the direction whether it is left or right using the negative and positive values of x, and write your own logic like if its left perform you action and if its right perform the both.

Hope it will help.